# The ring $k[x]/x^p$ is not regular?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R:=k[x]/x^p$ with a field $k$ of characteristic $p$.

Then this local ring $R$ is regular or not?

Comment: No, because regular local rings are domains. It doesn't matter that $k$ has characteristic $p$, only that $p>1$. Alternatively, and more easily, this ring has dimension zero. If a regular local ring has dimension zero, then its maximal ideal is equal to its square, hence is zero by Nakayama. So regular local rings of dimension zero are fields. Your ring is not a field.

Comment: Thak you very much. I understood.

Comment: @Keenan: In order to apply Nakayama, you need that the maximal is finitely generated. So probably add "noetherian" somewhere.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 6):

The ring $R=k[X]/(X^p)$ is a finite local $k$-algebra with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ generated by the image of $X$, so if it is regular, then $\dim(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)=\dim(R)=0$. By Nakayama's lemma, this implies that $\mathfrak{m}=0$, so $R$ is a field. But clearly $R$ is not a field, so $R$ is not regular.